# Google maps callback not loaded?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Google offers this script to initialize Google Maps:

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
```

The part I want to focus on is:

```
callback=initMap
```

Since the script is being loaded with `async defer` and is non-blocking , what actually happens when the `initMap` callback is being called while the file that holds this function is not yet loaded?

Assuming this function is being put into an external file and loaded after the Google maps script. This could possibly come from another server which might not be loaded in time when the callback tries to call the function.

Does it try to call the function and fail and only do this once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Since the script is being loaded with async defer and is non-blocking
>   , what actually happens when the initMap callback is being called
>   while the file that holds this function is not yet loaded?

You will get an exception similar to *`initMap is not defined`*.

The solution is to load the JavaScript files in correct order using `defer` attribute only:

```
<script defer src="https://example.com/initMap.js"></script>
<script defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
```

The `defer` attribute loads scripts in parallel but preserves order of execution (in sane browsers).

Another solution is to embed the `initMap` function inside the HTML page, and place the `<script defer>` or `<script async defer>` after it.